# Синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксис

Принято ли разбирать синтаксически словосочетания (как предложения)? Если да, то есть ли какой-нибудь особый порядок такого разбора?

Answer (score 1):

При синтаксическом разборе словосочетания определяется главное и зависимое (если считать словосочетаниями только сочетания слов с подчинительной связью, если нет, то сначала определяем сочинительное или подчинительное - такой точки зрения придерживается Бабайцева, а потом разбираем подчинительное далее), определяем части речи слов, входящих в словосочетания,вид словосочетания (глагольное, именное. наречное), вид подчинительной связи (согласование. управление, примыкание),

Answer (score 0):

Если считать словсочетаниями только подчинительные словосочетания, то разбор имеет следующую схему:
1.начальная форма;2.схема (модель);3.вид синтаксической связи; 4. способ подчинительной связи;5.грамматическое значение;6. тип по морфологической природе главного слова; 7. тип ко количеству компонентов; 8. тип по предсказуемости/непредсказуемости связи; 9. тип по степени обязательности зависимого компонента; 10. тип по наличию синтаксической связанности; 11. тип по степени модельности.